# Selenium/Beautifulsoup web scrape of Grainger

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium

This is my first time writing a web scrape using Selenium and Beautifulsoup. The website I'm scraping is https://www.grainger.com/ and I have it pulling a specific set of SKUs stored in an Excel file. To run a scrape of 1,000 items takes ~8 hours and I'm trying to scrape 30,000 items. Is there anywhere I can improve my scrape to have it run faster?

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from random import randint
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

# open the file
data = pd.read_excel(r'Grainger Sku List.xlsx','Sheet1') 
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe')
# get the urls
urls = data.URL
Graingerlist = []

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
    time.sleep(randint(1,11))
    try:
        Name = soup.find('h1',class_="lypQpT").text.strip()
    except:
        Name = 'Chceck Name'
    try:
        Price = soup.find('span',class_="vOg9Zc Jlt5uj").text.strip()
    except:
        pass
        try:
            Price = soup.find('span',class_="YrWqzV").text.strip()
        except:
            Price = 'Chceck Price'
    try:
        SPrice = soup.find('span',class_="vOg9Zc KHonQU Jlt5uj").text.strip()
    except:
        SPrice = 'No Sale Price'
    try:
        Item = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "vDgTDH"})
    except:
        Item = 'Chceck Item'        
    try:
        TierR = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "TfXnvH"})
    except:
        Tier = 'No Tier Price'
    try:
        Tier1R = TierR[0].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier1R = 'No Tier 1'
    try:
        Tier2R = TierR[1].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier2R = 'No Tier 2'
    try:
        Tier3R = TierR[2].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier3R = 'No Tier 3'
    try:
        Tier4R = TierR[3].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier4R = 'No Tier 4'
    try:
        Tier5R = TierR[4].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier5R = 'No Tier 5'
    try:
        Tier6R = TierR[5].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier6R = 'No Tier 6'    
    try:
        Tier7R = TierR[6].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier7R = 'No Tier 7'   
    try:
        TierP = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "MLh0qn"})
    except:
        TierP = 'No Tier Price'
    try:
        Tier1P = TierP[0].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier1P = 'No Tier 1'
    try:
        Tier2P = TierP[1].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier2P = 'No Tier 2'
    try:
        Tier3P = TierP[2].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier3P = 'No Tier 3'
    try:
        Tier4P = TierP[3].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier4P = 'No Tier 4'     
    try:
        Tier5P = TierP[4].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier5P = 'No Tier 5'
    try:
        Tier6P = TierP[5].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier6P = 'No Tier 6'
    try:
        Tier7P = TierP[6].text.strip()
    except:
        Tier7P = 'No Tier 7'                  
    try:
        ItemNum = Item[0].text.strip()
    except:
        ItemNum = 'Check Item Number'
    try:
        MPN = Item[1].text.strip()
    except:
        MPN = 'Check MPN'
    try:
        UOM = soup.find('span',class_="tqfrFT").text.strip()
    except:
        UOM = 'Chceck UOM' 
    try:
        Tax = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "sIWwJ-"})
    except:
        Tax = 'Chceck Taxonomy'
    try:
         Link = url
    except:
         Link = 'Chceck Link'   
    try: 
        Tax0= Tax[0].text.strip()
    except:
        Tax0 = 'No Tax0'
    try: 
        Tax1= Tax[1].text.strip()
    except:
        Tax1 = 'No Tax1'
    try: 
        Tax2= Tax[2].text.strip()
    except:
        Tax2 = 'No Tax2'
    try: 
        Tax3= Tax[3].text.strip()
    except:
        Tax3 = 'No Tax3'
    try: 
        Tax4= Tax[4].text.strip()
    except:
        Tax4 = 'No Tax4'
    try: 
        Tax5= Tax[5].text.strip()
    except:
        Tax5 = 'No Tax5'
    try: 
        Tax6= Tax[6].text.strip()
    except:
        Tax6 = 'No Tax6'        
    try: 
        Tax7= Tax[7].text.strip()
    except:
        Tax7 = 'No Tax7'            
    Grainger = {
        'Name': Name,
        'Price':Price,
        'Sale Price':SPrice,
        'Tier 1 Range':Tier1R,
        'Tier 1 Price':Tier1P,
        'Tier 2 Range':Tier2R,
        'Tier 2 Price':Tier2P,
        'Tier 3 Range':Tier3R,
        'Tier 3 Price':Tier3P,
        'Tier 4 Range':Tier4R,
        'Tier 4 Price':Tier4P,
        'Tier 5 Range':Tier5R,
        'Tier 5 Price':Tier5P,
        'Tier 6 Range':Tier6R,
        'Tier 6 Price':Tier6P,
        'Tier 7 Range':Tier7R,
        'Tier 7 Price':Tier7P,
        'Item #':ItemNum,
        'MPN': MPN,
        'UOM':UOM,
        'Tax0':Tax0,
        'Tax1':Tax1,
        'Tax2':Tax2,
        'Tax3':Tax3,
        'Tax4':Tax4,
        'Tax5':Tax5,
        'Tax6':Tax6,
        'Tax7':Tax7,
        'url': Link
             }

    Graingerlist.append(Grainger)
    print('Saving', Grainger['Name'])


    df = pd.DataFrame(Graingerlist)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    e = '{}-{}-{}'.format(now.year, now.month, now.day)

    df.to_excel(rf'GRG Sheet 1 {e}.xlsx', index=(False))
```

Comment: Are you doing this for fun/practice, or do you specifically need info from Grainger? If the latter, your approach is incorrect and you need to read the Integrated Ordering section of https://www.grainger.ca/en/content/services/ecommerce-solutions .

Comment: Please show a representative sample of your Excel file

Comment: It is not a "for fun" project but the link you posted does not relate to what im trying to do... as for the excel file its simply a list of urls in  column A that i want scraped like: https://www.grainger.com/product/10A593
https://www.grainger.com/product/10A598
https://www.grainger.com/product/10A666
https://www.grainger.com/product/10A994
https://www.grainger.com/product/10C002

Comment: I beg to differ: if you do what they suggest and contact them about integration options, they will almost surely recommend against scraping and toward the use of a pre-existing API

Comment: That option is for customers of Grainger  so it is not a viable option for my project. I welcome any recommendations on improving my existing code.

Comment: Until you describe what your project actually is, I do not believe you when you say that API use is not an option. Commerce integrations are not only for existing customers, and scraping is basically guaranteed to be slower and less stable.

Comment: My project is to scrape product name, price, sku, unit of measure, taxonomy, manufacturer part number from a distinct list of SKUs fed by an excel file. The code I posted does that and I simply asked for help to improve its speed. I appreciate you trying to give me another way to approach it but the method I've posted is the one I need to use right now. If there's no way to improve what I've posted then so be it, as I said in the start of my post this is my first attempt at it so I'm still learning.

Comment: How often is the Excel file expected to change?

Comment: The scrape will be run monthly and i expect items to be added and removed every time its ran since items are discontinued and replaced with new items

Comment: @SaraJ it should be fixed now, thank you

Comment: It seems like none of your example URLs have a "tier" section. Can you provide one that does?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually care about speed, this is not a serious attempt at commerce integration and you need to contact the vendor to get API details. You seem extremely resistant to this but it is the only path. If you do not do this, in a week or two the vendor could very easily change their class names and/or block your IP and your efforts will have been for naught. Said another way, Grainger has good reason to block you as you present a traffic load that does not match (and may interfere with) their intended use case. Quoting their [terms of access](https://www.grainger.com/content/mc/policies/terms-of-access),

> **C. Harm to Our Systems, Property and Security**
>
> When using the Grainger Property, you will not: [...] (ii) retrieve, index, scrape, data mine or otherwise gather any Grainger Content, Grainger Property, or other data, content, or materials (including through use of any robot, spider, screen scraping, web harvesting, data extraction, or similar software or technologies.

A half-measure that would be just as fragile but may somewhat increase speed is to avoid crawling individual URLs, and instead make a user product list (https://www.grainger.com/myaccount/mylistdetails) with your interesting products. I do not know the upper limit of the size of this list, but if you can get it all in one `GET` or even in paginated `GET`s then this should be faster.

Since your use case violates the vendor's terms of access I will not paste fully-formed alternative code, but I will offer bullet-point ways that your use of Python should improve:

Do not use Selenium. Use bare Requests.

Do not capitalise local variables.

Do not dump all of your code into the global namespace. Write functions, and add PEP484 typehints to their signatures.

Computers are good at loops: do not spell out all of the tier and taxonomy items manually; instead, form them over loops.

Do not call `.format()` with fragments of a datetime. Instead, embed the datetime format into an interpolated string, as in

```
f'GRG Sheet 1 {now:%Y-%m-%d}.xlsx'
```